# Laravel 5.4: Converting a raw SQL query in Laravel Eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to rewrite this SQL query but I'm stuck at this point

The query is meant to join the projects table to the project_progress table by using a sub-query to only join on the latest entry

```
SELECT * FROM projects
JOIN project_progress ON project_progress.id = 
(
    SELECT id FROM project_progress
    WHERE project_progress.project_id = projects.id
    ORDER BY project_progress.created_at DESC
    LIMIT 1
)
WHERE project_progress.next_action_date < NOW()
AND projects.status != 'Complete'
AND projects.member_id = 1
ORDER BY projects.title ASC
```

To:

```
$projects = App\Project::where('member_id', 1)
    ->join('project_progress', function ($join) {
        $join->on('project_progress.id', '=', function ($query) {
            $query->select('project_progress.id')
                ->from('project_progress')
                ->where('project_progress.project_id', 'projects.id')
                ->orderBy('project_progress.created_at', 'desc')
                ->limit(1);
        });
    })
    ->where('project_progress.next_action_date', '<', Carbon\Carbon::now())
    ->notCompleted()
    ->orderBy('projects.project_title', 'asc')
    ->get();
```

I think some thing is wrong with this line but I'm not sure how to write it

```
$join->on('project_progress.id', '=', function ($query) {
```

ErrorException (E_ERROR) strtolower() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given \vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Grammar.php

Comment: "I think some thing is wrong with this line" why do you get errors? Or are wrong results returned? You can use `->toSql()` function to check the generated SQL

Comment: ErrorException (E_ERROR) 
strtolower() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given
\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Grammar.php

Answer (score 0):

Use `where()`:

```
$join->where('project_progress.id', '=', function ($query) {
```